# How to create event listener for elements created dynamically without JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

I'm trying to delete JQuery from my website: because i use it in a short fraction of the application.

I only have one problem: **the Event Listener** for the elements i created dynamically after create the listener in Javascript.

In JQuery i created the listener as follow:

```
$(document).on('click', '.class_ElementTrigger', function() {    });
```

This method works fine: but I don't find the equivalent in which i call "Javascript Pure"

This other, the only one I found, don't works with the elements created dynamically :

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.el'), function (el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {

    }, false);
});
```

Anybody know the way to make it? Thanks!

Comment: do you probably run that code before pageload?

Comment: Hi. I run it after the pageload; but i have a table with ajax data. That is the problem... The elements "created" by ajax are loaded after the JavaScript event listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with jQuery, attach the event handler to a static container. You can then make checks within your event handler function for class names, ids etc against `e.target`.

Here's a (very) basic example:

```
document.onclick = function(e){
    if(e.target.classList.has('example')){
        alert('.class_ElementTrigger was clicked');   
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z5fhe46h/2/)

Note that I've used the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) object here.

Comment: May you modify this code to check if the element contains the class "example"?  My element (button) contain several class and this code not works... (¡Sorry! I know it's an abuse: but i dont know how i make it works...)

Comment: @MartaFernandez Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
 x=document.getElementsByClassName('.class_ElementTrigger');

  x.addEventListener('onclick',function(){
          //your logic          

   });
```

Comment: Sorry: this code not work how i need it; but thank you. (this not work with the elements created dynamically, i think)